# Forwarding the results of text processing commands to certain locations in an .ods file

Tags: openoffice.org, text-processing

I am looking for an efficient way to import the data from a bunch of text files into an .ods file. I have no problem in processing the text files with commands like grep and sed, however, I do not know if it is possible to redirect the results of these commands into a certain location in an ods file.

Comment: By ".ods file", I assume you mean an "OpenDocument Spreadsheet". Consider processing your text into a file of comma-separated values, and importing that into your OpenDocument Spreadsheet"

Answer (score 0):

The following article from Wikipedia will give you a hint:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification

Basically what you need to do (since you can't control the tags) is to add some sort of placeholder to ease the text replacement with sed/awk/whatever.

Just pay attention that these files are zipped (best described as Info-ZIP Application Note 970311, 1997) and you'll probably need to unzip or zcat them in order to process and zip them back once done.